# Drupal check boxes creation

Tags: php, drupal

I have the form in drupal7.

What i need is: i have category and sub category . I have to list these in checkboxes like

[image]

I used the code as

```
 $form['rate_the_room']['talent'] = array(
   '#prefix'=>'<h1>category:</h1>',
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => $sub_tal,

 );
```

Here $sub_tal is an array. If it is the single dimensional array it works fine.  Here how to pass an array(The category , sub categories are came from db). How to maintain this structure with this code.

Please help me thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any particular reason why these all need to be in one form element? If your data is set up properly, you can simply loop through them and create elements in a somewhat organized fashion.

```
function my_test_form($form_state) {
  // Assuming you have your data in a format like this
  $categories = array(
    'cat1' => array(
      '#title' => 'category 1',
      'sub1' => 'Subcat1',
      'sub2' => 'Subcat2',
    ),
    'cat2' => array(
      '#title' => 'category 2',
      'sub21' => 'Subcat21',
      'sub22' => 'Subcat22',
    ),
    'cat3' => 'category 3',
  );

  $elements = array();

  foreach ($categories as $cat => $data) {
    // If multidimensional, create parent and loop through children
    if (is_array($data)) {
      $elements[] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#title' => $data['#title'],
        '#return_value' => $cat,
      );

      foreach (element_children($data) as $subcat) {
        $elements[] = array(
          '#type' => 'checkbox',
          '#title' => $data[$subcat],
          '#attributes' => array(
            'style' => 'margin-left: 2em',
          ),
          '#return_value' => $cat . '-' . $subcat,
        );
      }

    }
    // Else, just create top level
    else {
      $elements[] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#title' => $data,
        '#return_value' => $cat,
      );
    }
  }

  // Group all of these elements together. They'll be submitted into the same array.
  $form['categories'] = $elements;
  $form['categories']['#tree'] = TRUE;
  $form['categories']['#prefix'] = '<div style="font-weight:bold" class="label">' . t('Checkboxes title') . ':</div>';

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#value' => t('Submit me'),
    '#type' => 'submit',
  );
  return $form;
}

function my_test_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $submitted_values = array_filter($form_state['values']['categories']);
}
```

**Renders as:**

[image: Categories image2]

And when the form is submitted, assuming some checkboxes were checked, `$submitted_values` looks like this:

```
array('cat2', 'cat2-sub21', 'cat2-sub22')
```

You can change the values of the checkboxes submitted to the submit handler by changing the `#return_value` attribute that I set on each checkbox above.

The submitted values are grouped together not only because they are all within the `$form['categories']` section, but also because `#tree` is set to `TRUE`.

Comment: Your solution works good with respect to the display. But I need the categories to be checkboxes instead of checkbox. So the name of the check box will be like category[] so that I can get the values through post and same for all subcategories it is subcategory[]. Is it possible? Please advise. Thanks

Comment: What you're describing is possible via multiple form elements. How exactly do you want the returned data to be formatted, for categories and subcategories? All in one array like `$form_state['category'] = array('cat1', 'sub1', 'sub2')` etc or in a nested array like `$form_state['category'] = array('cat1', 'cat2', array('sub1', 'sub2', 'sub21'))` etc?

Comment: All in one array should be good but the appearance should be like the image. So everything should come under one checkboxes title.

Comment: @Vasanthan.R.P - See my revised answer. I have added in grouping so that all of the checkboxes are submitted together into the same array. They also have a label in front of the group. Also updated screen shot.